# Sqlite insertOrThrow() failing with database file not found error

Tags: sqlite

I'm having a hard time getting any of the inserts to work with SqlLite. I have a table created with the following schema: 
create table drink_category ( _id integer not null primary key autoincrement, value unique);

When the attached code runs, I get a SQLiteCantOpenDatebaseException with the error message "cannot open database file (code 14)".

As you can see in the code, I access the table with a query without a problem. I also do a db.isOpen() to verify the database is OK. I have even added code after the block with the insert and everything works OK. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public Boolean add(String strValue)
{
    Boolean    bStatus  = true;
    String     strSql;
    String     sqlValue = strValue.replaceAll("'","\'\'");

    if (bStatus)
    {
        if (strValue.isEmpty())
        {
            BarDB.getInstance().setErrorMessage("No value entered.");
            bStatus = false;
        }
    }
    if (bStatus)
    {
               strSql = "select value from " + "drink_category" + " where value = '" + sqlValue + "' "; 
        Cursor cursor = SqlDbAdapter.getInstance().getDatabase().rawQuery(strSql, null);

        if (null == cursor)
        {
            BarDB.getInstance().setErrorMessage("Problem with the database.");
            bStatus = false;

        }
        else if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            BarDB.getInstance().setErrorMessage("A Drink Category with that name already exists.");
            bStatus = false;
        }
    }
    if (bStatus)
    {
        ContentValues cvValues = new ContentValues();
        cvValues.put("value", sqlValue);
        SQLiteDatabase db = SqlDbAdapter.getInstance().getDatabase();

        if (db.isOpen())
        {
            try
            {
                long lerror = db.insertOrThrow("drink_category", null, cvValues);
            }
            catch (SQLiteException sqle)
            {
                BarDB.getInstance().setErrorMessage(sqle.toString());
                bStatus = false;
            }
        }
    }
     return bStatus;
}
```

Comment: FOUND IT: I am running this on an emulator and I was storing the database file in /data/data. I guess when you do an insert, sqlite needs to write to a journal file and that directory is read only. I moved the database to /data/data/<appname>/databases and things are working OK now. A better error message would have been much  more helpful!

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT: I am running this on an emulator and I was storing the database file in /data/data. I guess when you do an insert, sqlite needs to write to a journal file and that directory is read only. I moved the database to /data/data//databases and things are working OK now. A better error message would have been much more helpful!